# Recognising different voices in Python

Tags: python, voice-recognition

I am currently working on a program which treats each voice differently. It involves the first person to ask questions, the second person answers those questions, and the program maintains a record/summary of the discussion. The catch is, I need to remove unnecessary information provided by the person answering, so it is necessary to differentiate between the two voices. Is there any Python library to take voice input and somehow flag the different voices?

Comment: If the sound comes from a phone call, or separate streams you can try/ask to have it recorded in stereo with one channel for each speaker (ie. questions on the left, answers on the right).

Comment: That is a smart way to go about it, thanks!